# "Buchungsangebot mit Option" translation to English

Tags: british-english, translation, german

I wonder whether I'm on the right Forum.

I need the translation of the German concept "Buchungsangebot mit Option" into English. It's about hotel rooms reservation.

I understand "Buchungsangebot mit Option" is a not binding room reservation, which the client has the right to accept within a certain time. Otherwise, the room gets released.

But I cannot find the translation into English for it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't find a decent translation for it because American hotels don't work that way. You could call it a (non-binding) booking offer. Not sure what the option is.

Comment: From the other point of view, it's a reservation that requires confirmation.

Comment: You might have better luck asking on [German.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com) where things like this are more on-topic

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean a **provisional booking** or **provisional reservation**.

I have no idea about the legal aspects of this vs the German version. In the UK at least, it not a common arrangement.

From https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/provisional

> 2 if an arrangement is provisional, the people involved have not yet said that they definitely want to do it
>   *We’ve made a provisional reservation for next week.*